# How do I link to authors post outside of the loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using UberMenu and they have been very helpful, but we have not been able to figure this out.

They have a shortcode to display recent post in the menu with image and title.

I want to add the author of the post under the title linked to the authors post.

Here is the current code:

```
function ubermenu_recent_posts($atts){

global $uberMenu;

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'num'       =>  3,      
    'img'       =>  'on',
    'img_width' =>  85,
    'img_height'=>  55,
    'excerpt'   =>  'off',
    'category'  =>  '',
    'default_img' => false,
    'offset'    =>  0,

), $atts));

$args = array(
    'numberposts'   =>  $num,
    'offset'        =>  $offset,
    'suppress_filters' => false
);

if(!empty($category)){
    if(is_numeric($category)){
        $args['category'] = $category;
    }
    else $args['category_name'] = $category;        
}

$posts = get_posts($args);


$class = 'wpmega-postlist';
if($img == 'on') $class.= ' wpmega-postlist-w-img';

$html= '<ul class="'.$class.'">';
foreach($posts as $post){

    $ex = $post->post_excerpt;
    if( $ex == '' && function_exists( 'wp_trim_words' ) ){  //wp_trim_words is a WP3.3 function
        $ex = $post->post_content;
        $ex = strip_shortcodes( $ex );

        $ex = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $ex);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 10);
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $ex = wp_trim_words( $ex, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    //$ex = apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt);

    $post_url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author );
    $author_id = $post->post_author;
    $post_comments = comments_popup_link( __('No comments', 'wellthemes'), __( '1 comment', 'wellthemes'), __('% comments', 'wellthemes'));


    $image = '';
    $w = $img_width;
    $h = $img_height;

    if($img == 'on') $image = $uberMenu->getPostImage($post->ID, $w, $h, $default_img);

    $html.= '<li>'. $image.
                '<div class="wpmega-postlist-title">
                <div class="wpmega-post-title"><a href="'.$post_url.'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></div>
                <div class="wpmega-post-author"><a href="'.get_author_posts_url($author_id).'"><span>by '.$author_name.'</span></a>'.$post_comments.'</div>
                </div>';

    if($excerpt == 'on')
        $html.= '<div class="wpmega-postlist-content">'.$ex.'</div>';

    $html.=     '<div class="clear"></div>'.
            '</li>';
}
$html.= '</ul>';

return $html;
}
add_shortcode('wpmega-recent-posts', 'ubermenu_recent_posts');  //legacy
add_shortcode('ubermenu-recent-posts', 'ubermenu_recent_posts');
```

If you mouse over the sports menu tab and mouseover the author name while on the home page you will see it links correctly, but if you click into any other page if removes the author fro the URL.

Site: http://mystreetlife.com/home

Comment: Can you post the full code please?  The get_the_author..() functions are template tags and how they work is dependent on how the loop is structured.  I'm surprised it works on the home page at all.

Comment: Added full code. Also i made some changes. `$author_id = $post->post_author;` and this `<div class="wpmega-post-author"><a href="'.get_author_posts_url($author_id).'"><span>by '.$author_name.'</span></a></div>` and everything seems to be working now. Now if I can only get the number of comments to work I would be set.